# Modifying existing Google analytics events, retaining data associations

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

We have numerous google analytics events that are setup and have existed for a couple years collecting data.

I want to add additional events and in some cases, modify some of the existing ones to report more specific info but a major stipulation is that the past historical recordings of these events which exist in GA currently are not lost.

What should I be aware of.. If I modify an event, how can I ensure that it remains associated with what it has been so the data connections remain?

If this doesn't make sense, I apologize, I'm having a hard time explaining this I know.

Answer (score 1):

If you change how events are reported to Google Analytics it will not cause historical data to change.   You will always be able to query the historical data is it has been reported.

If you change the "category" or "action" of any event going forward, then you may have to maintain two sets of reports -- one for historical data, and one for data from the time the change was made.